# Multiple token substitution for a string in react.js

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx, reduce

I have the following JSX code to substitute the tokens with values in the prompt:

```
const prompt = '[a]_[b]_[c]'
const tokens = ['[a]','[b]','[c]']
const values = ['A', 'BBB', 'CC']
const promptRes = tokens.reduce( (prevText, curText, i) => {
    prevText = prevText.replace(curText, values[i]) 
}, prompt)
console.log(promptRes) // Expected: 'A_BBB_CC'
```

But it gave me the following error:

*prevText = prevText.replace(curText, values[i])
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')*

It seems the initial value (i.e. prompt) cannot be used.

Please help:

1. Explain why that's a problem, and/or
2. Suggest a solution to this multiple token substitution problem without any loops (note that loops are not allowed in JSX)

Thank you!

Comment: You have to return something in every iteration of the `reduce`. Also, your code is plain javascript, no elements of jsx here

Answer (score 0):

You can read how to use `reduce` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const prompt = '[a]_[b]_[c]'
const tokens = ['[a]', '[b]', '[c]']
const values = ['A', 'BBB', 'CC']
const promptRes = tokens.reduce((prevText, curText, i) => {
  return prevText.replace(curText, values[i])
}, prompt)
console.log(promptRes) // Expected: 'A_BBB_CC'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should use return instead!  You saved my day.